# Why i keep getting 400 Bad Request response using guzzle

Tags: php, httprequest, guzzle, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to parse an HTML response from a server. but currently i am stuck with post request guzzle. I keep getting  400 Bad Request when i tried to make post request.

Error message:

```
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException  : Client error: `POST https://my-uat.testing.my/in` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Req (truncated...)
```

Here is my code. I hope i'm doing it right. I want to post the string trough API:

```
public function sendcs($chk_arr)
{

    $TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL=$chk_arr['TEST_RETURN_URL'];
    $TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL2=$chk_arr['TEST_RETURN_URL2'];
    $TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_ID=$chk_arr['TEST_TRANSACTION_ID'];
    $TRX_TRX_PRODUCT_ID=$chk_arr['TRX_PRODUCT_ID'];
    $TRX_CS_PAYMENT_METHOD='CS';
    $TRX_XYZ_TEST_ID=$chk_arr['XYZ_TEST_ID'];
    $TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_TIME=$chk_arr['TEST_TRANSACTION_TIME'];

    $str = '';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL2).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_ID).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_TRX_PRODUCT_ID).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_CS_PAYMENT_METHOD).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_XYZ_TEST_ID).'|';
    $str = $str. trim($TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_TIME);

    $file = "mchnts/" . env('WEB_XYZ_TEST_ID') . '/privatekey.pem';
    $exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists($file);
    if($exists)
    {
        $certloc = Storage::disk('local')->get($file);
    }else{
        abort(403);
        // dd('missing TEST public key');
        die();
    }

    $key = openssl_pkey_get_private($certloc);
    openssl_sign($str, $signature, $key);
    $checkSum = strtoupper(bin2hex( $signature ));
    
    $sPost = "";
    $sPost = $sPost . "TEST_RETURN_URL=" . $TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "TEST_RETURN_URL2=" . $TRX_TEST_RETURN_URL2 . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "TEST_TRANSACTION_ID=" . $TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_ID . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "TRX_PRODUCT_ID=" . $TRX_TRX_PRODUCT_ID . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "XYZ_TRANS_TYPE=" . $TRX_CS_PAYMENT_METHOD . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "XYZ_TEST_ID=" . $TRX_XYZ_TEST_ID . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "TEST_TRANSACTION_TIME=" . $TRX_TEST_TRANSACTION_TIME . "|";
    $sPost = $sPost . "XYZ_TRX_SIGNATURE=" . $checkSum;

    $client = new Client();
    $url= "https://my-uat.testing.my/in";
    // Make the POST request using Guzzle
    $response = $client->post($url, [
      'headers' => [
          'Host' => 'secure.example.com',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length' => strlen($sPost),
          'Accept' => '*/*',
      ],
      'verify' => false, // Disables SSL certificate verification
      'body' => $sPost,
    ]);

    // Get the response body
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    echo $body;
    // Return the response
    return $body;
}
```

What im trying to achieve is the result= $body able to load the HTML using DOMDocument

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$xp = new \DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//form[@method="post"]');
$result = $body;
$node = $nodes->item(0);
$url = $node->getAttribute('action');
```

Comment: Presumably, you sent something the remote server doesn't consider to be valid. Since we don't know _exactly_ what you sent, and we have _no idea_ what the remote server expects you to send, or what it would like you _not_ to send, it's really very difficult to make useful suggestions. If there is any extra detail within the response body (which you've truncated here) which explains the reason for the error, use that information to correct your code. If there isn't, consult the remote API's documentation and/or ask for support from the maintainer of the API.

Comment: The actual post body content you are sending, appears to be `name=value` pairs, separated by `|`. But that would not be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, as your Content-Type header says - that format uses `&` as the separator. (Actually, it still kinda would be, because you got _one_ `name=` there at the start, so without any `&`, _everything_ that follows would not be considered the value of that one and only parameter named `name` now. And apart from the fact, that you don't appear to have actually applied any URL encoding in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe can you suggest what i should be reading/research to solve this? i really dont have any idea what i should look into.thank you

Comment: @ADyson Actually i did not truncated the response body. that all it displayed when i  run  php artisan command:programname.extra details for the error "at /Users/azim/workspace/bayarwebpg_kembaliapi/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
    109|         if ($summary !== null) {
    110|             $message .= ":\n{$summary}\n";
    111|         }
    112| 
  > 113|         return new $className($message, $request, $response, $previous, $handlerContext);
    114|     }
    115| 
    116|     /**

Comment: Exception trace:

  1   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), [])
      /Users/azim/workspace/bayarwebpg_kembaliapi/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:72

  2   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
      /Users/azim/workspace/bayarwebpg_kembaliapi/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:209"

Comment: Probably the terminal or the php command is truncating it then, I would guess. Maybe get your code to log the full response to a separate file for inspection, in case there is extra useful content in there (as it clearly states that it's been truncated).

Comment: If you use this syntax, then you can simply pass an array with your parameter names and values, and don't have to handle any of the encoding and concatenation yourself: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params

Comment: @CBroe.it works.although now i encountered error at other part :) thank you so much